# Permalinks not working in Wordpress

Tags: permalinks, mod-rewrite

In wordpress I've chosen "**Day and name**" for permanlinks but I am getting 404. The modrewrite module is loaded, the .htaccess is

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data 274 nov.  23 13:10 .htaccess
```

i have put htaccess to 777 temporarily just to solve the problem but still it doesn't work

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

After changing "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All" in Apache configuration files, it works